# What exactly could cause the incompatibility of 30-pin, eDP, 2-lane laptop screens?

Tags: laptop, display, compatibility

I'm trying to replace the screen on a laptop.

I tried several screens that have same **eDP 30-pin** connector, all are **2-lane** (and apparently share the same data protocol), and not all of them work.

My question is, what could be the reason why eDP 30-pin screens are compatible or not?

---

Long story.

The laptop is Lenovo Thinkpad T550. There are several 1920×1080 IPS screens to consider:

- FRU 00HN836 = AU Optronics (AUO) B156HTN03.5 — must work, officially endorsed by Lenovo ([source, PDF](https://download.lenovo.com/parts/ThinkPad/t550_frubom_20160115.pdf))
- FRU 00HM082 = Innolux N156HGE-EA2 — must work, officially endorsed by Lenovo
- AUO B156HAN04.1 — works fine (worked before I broke the glass :)
- AUO B156HAN01.1 — does not work

The eDP pinout does not seem to allow any significant differences ([source, PDF](https://www.vesa.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/DisplayPort-DevCon-Presentation-eDP-Dec-2010-v3.pdf))

[image: eDP pinout]

Since all screens share the electrical  connector (eDP 30-pin) and data protocol (2-lane), I thought all must be compatible, but apparently they are not.

What could be the reason of such incompatibility? Knowing the answer would help me find a proper replacement (not necessarily officially supported by the laptop vendor).

Comment: The pin lines are not always using a common standard, one which is -5 ground on one pin can be +12 volt on another screen, etc. You need to find pin-outs for the devices you are working with to know the exact voltages, then you can change them if/when needed.

Comment: Thanks @vssher, I've added a relevant diagram, and I can't see any variety of power pins. Are you talking about a specific pin?

Comment: I don't know if this __example__ will help you but have a look at this page on Super User's sister site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239554/lvds-30-pin-cable-confusion

Comment: They have different Signal Interface model although all are DP(2 Lanes) with 30-pin and Reverse I/F(not sure what this means). See comparison: Signal Pin Configuration - EDP-30P2L-020A Signal Interface Model : MSAK24025P30 vs EDP-30P2L-020A for others <!-- dummy content to evade minimal edit length of 6 chars -->

Comment: Thanks, this may lead toward the answer. Did you mean the difference between EDP-30P2L-020**A** and EDP-30P2L-020**P**? Can you please elaborate your answer with links to specific datasheets?

Comment: See this - https://www.panelook.com/modelcompare.php?ids=27229,19048

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://m.panelook.com/modelcompare.php?ids=23644,21694,27229,19048) is the breakdown of the 4 panels you mentioned.

The one that worked was just eDP;
the ones officially endorsed are better with eDP1.2;
the one that didn’t work has eDP1.3.

So for the one you got to work worked because of backwards compatibility. Your laptop will never support eDP version 1.3 or newer, however eDP 1.2 still has amazing panel options for 15.6”. :)

[LG Display LP156WFC-SPDB](https://m.panelook.com/modeldetail.php?id=43481) is an example of a excellent option that should work perfectly with your laptop. :)

[Full list](https://m.panelook.com/modelcompare.php?ids=23644,21694,27229,19048,43481) including the one I just recommend for comparison. :)

Comment: Wow, thanks! I still have that defunct laptop, so this seems to be a chance to make it back to life!